# How to position one SVG onto another SVG at a specified position using python3 or INKSCAPE command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, svg, command-line, inkscape

I have 2 files **Canvas.svg** and **Rectangle.svg**. I want to place the Rectangle.svg onto Canvas.svg at `X-mm`,`Y-mm` co-ordinates. Is it possible to do this operation using **python3** or **INKSCAPE command line** ?

First preference is any python3 implementation.

[image]

**Thanks in Advance !!!**

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest a wrapper file that references both Canvas.svg and Rectangle.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="600" height="400" viewBox="0 0 600 400">
    <image xlink:href="Canvas.svg" width="600" height="400"/>
    <image xlink:href="Rectangle.svg" width="200" height="100"
      transform="translate(100, 200)"/>
</svg>
```

As an example: With the command `inkscape --export-type="pdf" wrapper.svg` a PDF file will be generated what is 600x400 pixel and has a default DPI of 96, resulting in a PDF with the size of 6.25in x 4.17in. The DPI can be controlled by the flag `--export-dpi=DPI`.

It is up to you calculate the sizes appropriate for metric units :-)

Reference: [MAN PAGE | Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html)

PS: I know that the namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink` can be omitted when using SVG in a browser, but here it is needed...